# PHPUnit PHP_Token_Class not found unless executed with --no-coverage

Tags: php, laravel, docker, testing, phpunit

Im currently having a problem on my PHPUnit.

It will throw the following when executed:

```
In Stream.php line 477:

Class 'PHP_Token_CLASS' not found
```

However, the test will just proceed if added the option below:

> ./phpunit --no-coverage

but its difficult to monitor the test since it has no coverage.

Im using docker for windows.

I have tried several things such as rebuilding the docker container, config clear on artisan, composer dumpautoload, deleted vendor directory and then running composer install, using the option --coverage-text and --coverage-xml but nothing seems to work.

Thank you.

[UPDATE]

Here is my composer.json file

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2|^8.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.12.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
        "juampi92/cursor-pagination": "^1.6",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.18.35",
        "laravel/passport": "^9.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "mustache/mustache": "~2.5",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `Stream.php` ? Is it a vendor file ? Also, can you share your `composer.json`, please ?

Comment: Already updated with composer.json. That's also my concern, I can't seem to find the `Stream.php` file on my project, im using VSCode.

Comment: I did not find anything, I have your composer. Just update everything to the latest version with `composer update`.